# Create an image from a Swing-GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, printing

Is it possible to create an image from an existing Swing-GUI programmatically?

What I want is, that the GUI can be printed out, therefore I need an Image, as the printer only takes images to print...

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/). You can make an image of any component.